# ORACLE SQL Status check trigger

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I wanted to create a trigger which when a new order is inserted in the ORDERS table the trigger updates the status level of a customer in the CUSTOMER table, depending on how many orders they have made. If a customer has 0 orders his status level is 'new' else if he has more than 1 he is a 'standard' customer.

The trigger below works if I add the customer_no in manually:

```
create or replace TRIGGER STATUS_CHECK
AFTER INSERT ON ORDERS
DECLARE
  n INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(ORDER_NO)
  INTO n 
  FROM ORDERS
  INNER JOIN CUSTOMER
  ON CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_NO
  WHERE CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO = '01';

  IF(n > 1) THEN
  UPDATE CUSTOMER
  SET CUSTOMER.STATUS_LEVEL = 'STANDARD'
  WHERE CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO = '01';
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: Why you even need the trigger? How in the world a costumer that you are INSERTING can have an order?! You just inserted it! Just set the status field to new and create your trigger on the orders table.

Comment: You can reference the inserted row using `:new` rowtype variable, i.e. `WHERE CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO = :new.CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_NO`. However, you are trying to query the same table you are changing, so you might run into `ORA-04091: table is mutating`.

Comment: That said, are you sure it's `(n>1)` and not `(n>0)`? If even a single order makes the customer "standard", you don't need a select since you're doing exactly that - inserting a single order. Just update the customer using `:new.CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_NO`